# How do I manage last level cache among virtual machines?

Tags: virtualization, cache

Let's say I am gonna run a server to lend virtual machines to clients, like other CSP vendors do. My server has 20 cores, so there will be a total of 5 instances with 4 cores.

What I am worried about is sharing the last level cache. I want all instances to nicely share the LLC but there must be some workloads such as streaming that trying to consume almost all capacity, resulting in undermining other workloads' performance.

In this case, or in the usual cases of famous CSP vendors, what can the manager do? Is there any solution other than Intel CAT? Or the situation that I'm concerned about won't happen?

I might have violated some asking rules of this site. Sorry for your inconvenience in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your workload on the hardware and software environments you are considering. Ideally actual production work, but short of that simulate what clients would be doing: transactional, file transfer, encoding media, whatever. Find technical blogs for inspiration. For example, [Cloudflare's "Gen X" hardware selection](https://blog.cloudflare.com/impact-of-cache-locality/) is lacking in scientific discipline, but they are right to consider caches in their Intel Xeon Platinum 6162 vs AMD EPYC 7642 competition.

Several vendors can deliver 20+ core CPUs, and they differ on L3 cache. AMD [EPYC has L3 in each 4 core complex](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Core_Complex). IBM [POWER9 has L3 dedicated per 2 cores](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/ibm/microarchitectures/power9#Memory_Hierarchy). Intel Xeon [Cascade Lake has L3 shared across all cores](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/cascade_lake#Memory_Hierarchy). Locating caches as close to the core as possible shaves off cycles of latency, possibly making a difference to performance.

CPU caches tend to be less shared system wide than memory. In designs where the cache is dedicated to a core complex, a remote VM's 4 cores is not going to steal from some other cores. Yes, if something is churning the L3 cache that will hurt the hit ratio and need to go to memory more, but that depends on workload.

First test with an unaware scheduler and no QoS, as in don't explicitly manage L3. Even a naïve assignment to cores should give cores a roughly equal share of cache. Find where the bottlenecks truly are, could equally be storage or network or a hundred other places.

Should you need fine control of cache, ask your vendors how to do that on your chosen CPU and hypervisor. Intel has Resource Director. AMD has Platform Quality of Service. Both are showing up in the Linux kernel, [AMD more recently](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/cover/991227/). But do this after testing, so you are informed with how hard your workload hits the cache.

Comment: I am not actually gonna run a server, was just curious how real CSP vendors manage their cache. I believe they leverage cache management support from each chip maker. Thank you for your kind explanation!

Comment: On Server Fault I assume you wish to actually do the thing you are describing. Its about solving real business problems with IT, not dreaming up what some other service provider does in theory. Control of CPU cache is a relatively advanced thing, which might not be necessary if you don't oversubscribe CPUs.